# How to send POST request to Wordpress website and do some actions

Tags: wordpress, api, post, http-post

I am new to WordPress, what I want to do is to send POST request in JSON format to WordPress website and basis of that request I want to send an email.
what I want to know is...
endpoint to send request?
what functions or files will be use to handle post request

thanks.

Comment: One option is to do a custom wp-page which will handle your request. Mainly add on current theme the file `page-customxxx.php` and the logic inside where `yoursite\customxxx` will be the end-point(manually add code there), .

Comment: if i use that way the new custom page would be index on google search? right?? any other way ??

Comment: and its not secure option to do like this.

Comment: Regarding google, if standard output (GET) is nothing or maybe even a faulty status, then what to index ?

Comment: Regarding security, now if it's accessed inside wp-framework checking user-login is doing that.  If it's accessed from outside , even with nothing else configure on security  and based just on response via post it's also very hard to guess what's are proper input params in order to have a proper response. Also you could take a look further how to integrate basic-security.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: actually i don't want any response after post request to wordpress,
what i just want for example if request have parameters 'sock-updated' so just send mail to some email address which is inside wordpress database.

Comment: fine, then create a new page, manually add code, check post_params and if is ok send mail(s). That's all (do not even have to configure something on security and it will be available from any were ... but with out proper params will do nothing)

Comment: what they suggested in that post are you satisfied with that??
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253486/how-to-receive-http-post-in-wp
and you suggesting me to follow the same way?

Comment: that doing something else, basically added a new wp-post (not custom request via post) and on insert in wp-db something else will be done ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to do the following:

1. Create a blank page and remember slug (here test-mypost)
   [image]

[image]

2. Create and add code to custom .php (page-test-mypost.php)
   Have to be inside current theme (on same level as style.css ... root)

[image]

2.1. Add logic to page (`test-mypost.php`)
(eg: if request type is post and param1 is something then send mails)

3. Test page(`yoursite/test-mypost`)

[image]

Note: For how to write proper post request and send mail there are lot's of online docs very easy to find via a trivial search